# Can't solve second order ODE with variation of parameters or undetermined coefficients

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve $$y''+4y' +y=\frac{e^{-2x}}{x^2}.$$

The homogenous equation is easy enough to solve and I got 
$$y(x) = c_1e^{-2 + \sqrt{3}} + c_2e^{-2 - \sqrt{3}}$$
Doing variation of parameters, however, I got stuck when I got to the integrals
$$-\int \frac{e^{2x + \left(-2 + \sqrt{3} \right)}}{x^2(2\sqrt{3})}dx$$
and
$$\int \frac{e^{2x + \left(-2 - \sqrt{3} \right)}}{x^2(2\sqrt{3})}dx.$$
When I looked to wolfram alpha for help with the integrals it showed me

[image]

and I'm unfamiliar with the $Ei(x)$ function that it uses. So I decided that undetermined coefficients might be a better choice instead, but I have no idea where to get started. Could someone lead me down the right path?

Comment: If there's an exponential integral appearing like that, the answer is not going to simplify into elementary functions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Does that mean it can't be solved using undetermined coefficients as well? This was one of my exam questions today in a introduction to ODE course so I'm wondering if it is unsolvable for someone at my level.

Comment: I would expect undetermined coefficients would give you another DE you can't solve with elementary functions. I think, as @Mike says in his answer, it's most likely to be a copying error.

Comment: You can't solve it using undetermined coefficients. The RHS function is not in the form of an exponential times a polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, there are 2 possibilities here.  The first possibility is that since the integral does not appear to be elementary, you were not meant to simplify it and can leave it as is.

The second possibility is the problem was copied wrong (either copied down wrong or a typo in the source) where there should have been a $4$ as the $y$ coefficient, in which case, multiplying both sides by $e^{2x}$ would yield

$$(ye^{2x})''=\frac1{x^2}$$

which can be easily solved by integrating twice.

Comment: So there are no other possibilities?